# My code is working on local but doesnt work in server

Tags: php, html

i have 6 php pages, all work perfectly on pc and on host. except one, my search.php doesn't work on host (by the way it works on pc perfectly too). Somehow when i try to run search.php i don't even get error, only thing which i get is white screen. Here my codes ;

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!$_SESSION['auth'])
{
echo 'bu sayfaya erişim izniniz yok.';
header("Location: uyegirisi.html");
}
?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">
<head>

<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
<title>First try</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>



<style>
    li
      {
        display: inline;
        padding: 0px 20px 0px 20px;
      }

    ul
      {
        padding:10px;
        background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
      }

    a
      {
        color: black;
        font-size: 30px;
      }

    p
      {
        color: #0f0f0f;
        font-size: 24px;
        font-family: Helvetica;
      }

    .bor
      {
        font-size: 23px;
        border:2px;
      }

    .hr
    {
      color : #0000F8;
      size : 4;
    }
</style>

</head>
<body>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4"></div>
<div class="col-md-4" align="center">
   <header>
     <ul>
       <li><a href="musterikayit.html">Kayıt ekranı</a></li>
         <li><a href="logout.php"> Çıkış Yap</a></li>



    </ul>
  </header>
          <form action="musteriarama.php" method="get">
              <div class="hiza">
                <label for="Arama"></label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Arama" name="Arama">
                  </br>
                  </br>
                  <input class="but btn btn-primary btn-lg" type="submit" name="gonder" value="Müşteri Ara">

              </div>
         </form>

</div>
  <div class="col-md-4"></div>
</div>


</body>
</html>





<?php


$db =new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '' , 'musteritakip');
if($db->connect_errno) die ('Bağlantı hatası:' . $db->connect_errno);

if(isset($_GET['gonder'])){

#Ekleme işlemi

$stmt = $db ->prepare("select * from musteri_bilgileri where (isim like ?)");
if($stmt === FALSE) die("Sorgu hatası". $db ->error);
$ara ='%'.$_GET['Arama'].'%';
$stmt->bind_param("s", $ara);
$stmt->execute();
$sonuc =$stmt->get_result();


if($sonuc -> num_rows <1) die("<p>"."bulunamadı");




while ($row = $sonuc->fetch_array())
  {
    echo '<div>';
    echo '<p>'.$row['isim'];
    echo '&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp;';

    echo $row['soyad'];
    echo '&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp';

    echo '<form action="detaylar.php" method="post">';
    echo'<input type="hidden" value="'.$row['id'].'" name="gelenid">';
    echo '<input type ="submit" value="Detaylar" style="margin-bottom:-35px;" name="detaylargonder"></input>';
    echo '<hr width="100%" >';

    echo '</form>';



    echo '</br>';
    echo '</br>';
    echo '</div>';
 }

 }
?>
```

Comment: What's exactly not working?

Comment: please put error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On'); on the top of your file and check

Comment: Maybe your server won't use localhost as a database source.

Comment: remove the space of header function i.e make your `header("Location:uyegirisi.html");` like this and continue further

Comment: Have you tried telling the client "Works on my machine"?

Comment: nothing does work, the think that i get is just white screen @IceJOKER

Comment: i dont get error, what should i check ? @Coold
edit: i didnt see what you wrote on the top sorry, i'll check

Comment: Check error logs in /var/log/apache2/error.log

Comment: i tried but didnt work @dod29

Comment: you have to put error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 'On'); just after  <?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 'On');

Comment: how should i do this ? i cant find the path which you are talking about @Coold

Comment: what are you using LAMP/WAMP??

Comment: i put the code on the top of my codes and get 404 not found error and im using xammp @Coold

Comment: this is interesting because my musteriarama.php is in the server but i get 404 not found error

Comment: In your php.ini file check for display_errors. I think it is off or reinstall xampp

Comment: i think i cound't explain myself , my codes is working perfectly in xammp but doesn't work on the server like godaddy..

Comment: You have to fix the 404 error.

Comment: now i fixed 404 error, and still get nothing @JayBlanchard

Comment: check if everything is install properly on your server, php, mysql. check the details of godaddy phpmyadmin, its hostname as well

Comment: White screen is a typical indication of errors. Check the logs

Comment: i know There is nothing wrong with my godaddy server because mine 5 php pages connecting server and working perfectly, only one page doesn't work. i checked many times if i have connection error but everything is alright about server @Coold

Comment: log onto the command prompt, and goto sudo nano /var/log/apache2/error.log and post lsat 10 lines here

Comment: <?php
session_start();
if(!$_SESSION['auth'])
{
echo 'bu sayfaya erişim izniniz yok.';
header("Location: uyegirisi.html");
}
?> put this after </head> tag or body tag

Answer (score -1):

You must have missed something while you were uploading it. You haven't clearly described what's not working or about the error, we can only advice you.Follow below steps to solve your issue:

1. First add error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 'On'); at top of your script.
2. Check the browser's console log's, it will display relevant errors.
3. As you are getting blank page, please check your code, you might be getting 500 internal server error when you haven't code it correctly.
4. Check your syntax.
5. Check your application & DB configuration.